# Issue with "autoresizingMask" with two UITextViews

Tags: ios, resize, uitextview, overlap, autoresizingmask

I have a problem with "autoresizingMask" with two UITextView. When I resize the two UITextViews, overlaps the first above the second. 
I attached an image to explain the problem.

Thanks!

[image]

Update: I put the revenant code

[UIView]

```
self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

// Configure title label
_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(4.0, 4.0, self.bounds.size.width - 8.0, 33.0);
_titleLabel.backgroundColor = APP_COLOR(1.0);
_titleLabel.font = FONT_LATO_BOLD(18.0);
_titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[self addSubview:_titleLabel];

// Question textView
_questionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(_titleLabel.bounds), (usableHeight / 2.0) - 4.0)];
_questionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
_questionTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[self addSubview:_questionTextView];    

// Answer textView
_answerTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(_questionTextView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(_questionTextView.frame) + 8.0, CGRectGetWidth(_questionTextView.bounds), (usableHeight / 2.0) - 4.0)];
_answerTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
_answerTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self addSubview:_answerTextView];
```

Comment: Without more details on how you set the masks and how you resize the views it will be difficult to help. Update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: rmaddy, I updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The autoresize is working fine.

The two views just don't fit together in the parent view.

You have to adjust the view height manually.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try to add views to "container" view and resize them together